# ScrollView not working in a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, scrollview

i want to make layout scrollable with scrollview but its not working at all.tried to change scrollview with NestedScrollView but the problem still same. this layout used in fragment. put LinearLayout inside the scrollview as a view. can anyone help me to correct my code if i am doing wrong ? below is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ui.jobCalendar.JobCalendarFragment">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:headerColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_calendar"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                <TextView
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    style="@style/TextContent.Black"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="Schedule"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/listJob"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/job_row">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You should use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`

Comment: What is the height of your `CalendarView` and what is the height of the `RecyclerView`? Probably `RecyclerView` intercepts all scroll events.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

> 1) Change root layout to `RelativeLayout`
>
> 2) Set **height** of ScrollView to `wrap_content`
>
> 3) Change **height** of ScrollView child which is LinearLayout to
>   `match_parent`

4)add this line to Host `activity` of that `fragment`

```
 <activity
            android:name="Activity_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
```

Finally the `xml` looks like:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.jobCalendar.JobCalendarFragment">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView
                android:id="@+id/calendarView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:headerColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_calendar"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/TextContent.Black"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Schedule"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/listJob"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/job_row">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you tell me the problem ?

Comment: stucking on recyclerview scroll ?

Comment: the view is stuck. wont scroll

Comment: i want to scroll the calendarview to see the recyclerview. because it is in bottom of the layout. but cannot scroll. its stuck

Comment: same :( is it possible the problem is because the recyclerview inside ?

Comment: yes change the height of recycler view to something 200dp and check it , actually there should be workout to be used for recycler view in scrollview

Comment: recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); use this :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get rid of those settings inside the ScrollView attribute.

Basically short it down to

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Put the rest of the settings inside a RelativeLayout that is included inside the ScrollView like this:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        ======== put all the rest of your settings from scrollvide here =====>
              <CONTENT> add here the rest of your code </CONTENT> 
    </RelativeLayout>
</Scrollview>
```